# Zurb Foundation background color outside grid

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure out how to create a layout like this:

[image: mockup]

My grid size equals to the width of white area. I have no problems with dark blue Top Bar that occupies the whole width of the page, but I don' t know how to create light-blue sides, as they are outside of foundation grid.  If I change body background to light blue then foundation grid in the middle becomes blue as well.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: show what you have tried so far - we're not psychic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body { background-color: blue; }

.row { background-color: white; }
```

The `body` background color will occupy the whole page, and the background color of `row` will be superposed to that of `body`.

Answer (score 2):

`foundation_and_overrides.scss` file has a variable called `$body-bg` which accepts any color you want.

If you use this approach - don't forget to remove any styling of body in `scaffolds.css.scss` (otherwise it may override anything you specified in foundation settings).